# How to edit the photo of a Facebook post in Graph Facebook API?

Tags: java, facebook-graph-api, restfb

I want to write a JAVA program to create posts including images, for our clients Facebook pages.
using this endpoint `https://graph.facebook.com/{{page_id}}/photos`
and defining the page_access_token, the text message and URL of the photo I can do it.
In the following example I have created `page_access_token` and `page_id` in **Base Environment**.

> {
> "url":"Path_to_the_photo",
> "message":"The Desired Text"
> }

As you can see in this photo, the request to create the post is Successful.

[image: Insomnia Request to Create]

However I want to be able to edit this photo when it is needed, but I cannot find the endpoint in the documentation [Developers Facebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IkcM6.jpg).

I noticed that using `https://graph.facebook.com/v19.0/{{page_post_id}}` endpoint I can edit the text but not the photo. Does anyone have the idea how I can tackle this?

PS: I have successfully created the application with the full access and the following permissions:

1. read_insights
2. pages_manage_cta
3. pages_show_list
4. pages_messaging
5. pages_read_engagement
6. pages_manage_metadata
7. pages_read_user_content
8. pages_manage_ads
9. pages_manage_posts
10. pages_manage_engagement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. First we need to send a post request to the endpoint:
1-
[https://graph.facebook.com/{{page_id}}/photos](https://graph.facebook.com/%7B%7Bpage_id%7D%7D/photos)

```
{
  
   "published":false,
   "url":"Path to your photo"
}
```

on success reading the id.
2- Then another post request to
[https://graph.facebook.com/{{page_post_id}}](https://graph.facebook.com/%7B%7Bpage_post_id%7D%7D)

```
{
  
    "attached_media":[{"media_fbid":"the id you get from the previous request", "message":"media message"}],
   "message":"your probable new message"
}
```